# Flex: Content not Rendering Correctly After Transitioned State Change

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, render, state, transition

I have a component with 2 states and I have added transitions for switching between the states, where 2 Move affects are applied to 2 different objects. This all works fine, however, after the transition from the first state to the second has completed the second state doesn not render correctly. It contains a TextInput control which is not visible, and a Button with a custom skin that is only sometimes visible and vanishes if you click on it. I have tried called invalidateDisplayList() and validateNow() after loading the second state but that has done nothing. I also have a VBox with a cornerRadius property set, strangely this does not seem to apply anymore and the corners are square, where they displayed correctly before I added the transition in. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Here is the code for my states and their transitions:

```
<!-- different states of this component -->
<mx:states>
    <s:State name="useForFree"
             enterState="renderState()"/>
    <s:State name="enterLicence"
             enterState="renderState()"/>
</mx:states>


<!-- transitions between different states -->
<mx:transitions>

    <!-- transition from useForFree to enterLicence state -->
    <s:Transition id="toEnterLicence"
                  fromState="useForFree"
                  toState="enterLicence">
        <s:Parallel id="p1"
                    targets="{[freeBtn, _enterLicenceMask]}">               
            <s:Move yFrom="250"
                    yTo="0"
                    duration="500"
                    targets="{[freeBtn]}"/>
            <s:Move yFrom="289"
                    yTo="39"
                    duration="500"
                    targets="{[_enterLicenceMask]}"/>
        </s:Parallel>       
    </s:Transition>

    <!-- transition from enterLicence to useForFree state -->
    <s:Transition id="toUseForFree"
                  fromState="enterLicence"
                  toState="useForFree">
        <s:Parallel id="p2"
                    targets="{[enterLicenceBtn, _useForFreeMask]}">             
            <s:Move yFrom="0"
                    yTo="240"
                    duration="500"
                    targets="{[enterLicenceBtn]}"/>
            <s:Move yFrom="-250"
                    yTo="0"
                    duration="500"
                    targets="{[_useForFreeMask]}"/>
        </s:Parallel>       
    </s:Transition>
</mx:transitions>
```

and here is the code for my layout:

```
<mx:Canvas id="freeStateCanvas"
           width="100%">

    <mx:VBox width="100%"
             horizontalAlign="center"
             top="0"
             mask="{_useForFreeMask}">

        <mx:VBox id="freeBox"
                 includeIn="useForFree">
            <s:Label text="some text"/>
            <s:Spacer height="20"/>
            <s:Image source="image path"/>
            <s:Spacer height="20"/>
            <mx:Button id="connectBtn"/>
            <s:Spacer height="10"/>
            <mx:HBox >
                <s:Label text="some text"/>/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>

        <s:Label text="some text"
                 includeIn="useForFree"/>           
    </mx:VBox>

        <mx:Button id="enterLicenceBtn"
                   includeIn="useForFree"/>

</mx:Canvas>

<!-- enter licence state -->

<mx:Canvas id="enterLicenceStateCanvas"
           width="100%">

        <mx:VBox id="enterLicenceBox"                    
                 mask="{_enterLicenceMask}"
                 includeIn="enterLicence">

            <s:Label text="some text"/>
            <s:Spacer height="20"/>
            <s:TextInput id="licenceInput"
                         width="200"
                         height="30"/>
            <s:Spacer height="20"/>
            <mx:Button id="registerBtn"/>
            <s:Spacer height="10"/>
            <mx:HBox>
                <s:Label text="some text"/>
                <s:Label text="some more text"/>
            </mx:HBox>
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:Button id="freeBtn"
                   includeIn="enterLicence"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```

where the variables being set as masks are UIComponent instances where I have used their graphics property to draw a rectangle.

Comment: Hi Heather, can you provide sample code of the issue? (stripping away an non-essentially code and just leaving the state changes and transitions)  Generally speaking I haven't had issues with transitions and state changes but I've mostly worked in the 3.4 SDK, also if you respond with code please specify the particular version of the Flex SDK you're using.

Comment: Hi, I am using SDK 4.6, I'll edit my post to include my code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found what the problem was, but thanks for trying to help shaunhusain.

In my code you can see I have 2 VBox containers called "freeBox" and "enterLicenceBox" and these actually had a white background and rounded corners, and a DropShadowFilter applied to them (I removed these properties when putting up the code as I felt they were irrelevant, that was a mistake).

This DropShadowFilter was the cause of all my problems and on removing it, the transitions worked fine and all content was rendered correctly. I assume this is just a strange Flex bug, and I didn't find a workaround, I just used images as the box backgrounds for a quick fix.

Comment: glad you got it figured out I believe you should be able to accept your own answer since you were able to at least figure out a work-around if you'd like.